# How to check if a group has three consecutive values in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table `games` with values such as:

```
+----------+------+
|  game    | year |
+----------+------+
| Football | 1999 |
| Football | 2000 |
| Football | 2001 |
| Football | 2002 |
| Cricket  | 1996 |
| Tennis   | 2001 |
| Tennis   | 2002 |
| Tennis   | 2003 |
| Tennis   | 2009 |
| Golf     | 1994 |
| Golf     | 1996 |
| Golf     | 1997 |
+----------+------+
```

I am trying to see if a game has an entry with a minimum three consecutive years in the table. My expected output is:

```
+----------+
|  game    |
+----------+
| Football |
| Tennis   |
+----------+
```

Because:

- Football has four entries out of which four are consecutive years => `1999, 2000, 2001, 2002`
- Tennis has four entries out of which three are consecutive years => `2001, 2002, 2003`

In order to find the rows with a minimum three consecutive entries I first partitioned the table on `game` and then checked difference between the current and the next row as below:

```
select game, year, case
    when (year - lag(year) over (partition by game order by year)) is null then 1
    else year - lag(year) over (partition by game order by year)
end as diff
from games
```

Output of the above query:

```
+----------+------+------+
|  game    | year | diff |
+----------+------+------+
| Football | 1999 | 1    |
| Football | 2000 | 1    |
| Football | 2001 | 1    |
| Football | 2002 | 1    |
| Cricket  | 1996 | 1    |
| Tennis   | 2001 | 1    |
| Tennis   | 2002 | 1    |
| Tennis   | 2003 | 1    |
| Tennis   | 2009 | 6    |
| Golf     | 1994 | 1    |
| Golf     | 1996 | 2    |
| Golf     | 1997 | 1    |
+----------+------+------+
```

I am not able to proceed from here on getting the output by filtering the data for each game with its difference.

Could anyone let me know if I am in the right track of the implementation? If not, how do I prepare the query to get the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a self join approach here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT g1.Game
FROM games g1
INNER JOIN games g2
    ON g2.Game = g1.Game AND g2.Year = g1.Year + 1
INNER JOIN games g3
    ON g3.Game = g2.Game AND g3.Year = g2.Year + 1;
```

### Demo

The above query requires any matching game to have at least one record whose year can be found in the following year, and the year after that as well.

Comment: I would just note that, in my view, this scales horribly tho (readability-wise). If you ever need to change the number of contiguous years to say, 8, you need to add another 5 joins.

Comment: @IgorM Yes...I didn't give much care to the general sequence of N years case.  For just a run of 3 years, the above should work fine, especially if we index.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your initial approach is correct. You were actually really close to fully figuring it out yourself.

What I would do is alter `LAG` a bit:

```
year - LAG(year, 2) OVER (
    PARTITION BY game
    ORDER BY year
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```

For each row, this will compare the difference between the year from current row and the year from (current - 2)th row.

If it is the third consecutive row it will yield `2` which you can filter in `where` clause.

If your data contains duplicates you need to group by `game, year` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` and `lead()` and compare them to the current Year:

```
with u as
(select *, case
when lag(Year) over(partition by Game order by Year) = Year - 1
and lead(Year) over(partition by Game order by Year) = Year + 1
then 1 else 0
end as consec
from games)
select distinct Game
from u
where consec = 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1d48fe04800f9280d696885d6b5dac2)

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE(Common Table Expression) and the useful ROW_NUMBER window function this can be easily solved.

```
WITH CTE (name, RN) AS (
select name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name order by year) RN
        from game)
Select Distinct name
from CTE 
Where RN >= 3
```

Comment: Perhaps you could convert this sqlserver code to mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon CTE document: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/  and here is ROW_NUMBER document: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/. What is wrong ?

Comment: Backticks are used in mysql to qualify identifiers not square brackets https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries

Comment: This only tells you that there are three entries, not three consecutive ones.

Comment: @IgorM My fault. You are right. I will improve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql